# Rails Devise API - Login route responds with `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rails-api

I'm currently using Devise with my Rails API app to authenticate users using devise-jwt.

This is what my User model looks like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :jwt_authenticatable,
         jwt_revocation_strategy: JWTBlackList
end
```

And `config/routes.rb` is set up like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,
         path: '',
         path_names: {
           sign_in: 'login',
           sign_out: 'logout',
           registration: 'signup'
         },
         controllers: {
           sessions: 'sessions',
           registrations: 'registrations'
         }
end
```

This is the sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  private

  def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
    render json: resource
  end

  def response_to_on_destroy
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

and the registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    render_resource(resource)
  end
end
```

I ran some Rspec tests shown below which were successful -

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SessionsController, type: :request do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:url) { '/login' }
  let(:params) do
    {
      user: {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }
    }
  end

  context 'when params are correct' do
    before do
      post url, params: params
    end

    it 'returns 200' do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it 'returns JTW token in authorization header' do
      expect(response.headers['Authorization']).to be_present
    end

    it 'returns valid JWT token' do
      decoded_token = decoded_jwt_token_from_response(response)
      expect(decoded_token.first['sub']).to be_present
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run the following POST request to `/login` on Postman I get the following message:

[image: postman request]

On the right hand side you are able to see the rails console and server, showing the credentials are correct, but still we get 401

Any clues on what might be wrong? It's been difficult finding good resources on Devise using Rails API.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you share controller code as well?

Comment: does your application controller have `protect_from_forgery` statement?

Comment: @Nithin it does not, is this needed?

Comment: @GaganGupta I've added the code snippets, sorry for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging through the SessionsController I found the reason it returned 401:
`warden` was trying to authenticate an empty body. Fixed this by added `Content-Type` to the request header

Comment: Some configurations needed for devise to work in API only apps https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805522/6203172

Comment: can u explain that @john